# gist vscode - GIST ERROR: Could Not Create test > Reason: Bad credentials

Tags: visual-studio-code

f1 -> select profile (выбираю из списка мой профиль). по логике коннект есть.
далее нажимаю добавит gist и выдает вот такую ошибку GIST ERROR: Could Not Create test> Reason: Bad credentials

где я ошибся.
спасибо

Answer (score 1):

1. Устанавливаем расширение "gist" в "Visual Studio";
2. Заходим на главную своего профиля в Github, то есть "https://github.com/settings/profile" далее "Developer sesttings" далее "Personal acces tokens" выбираем "generate new token",
   Генерируя токен, нужно поставить галочку на gist. и копируем наш сгенерированный код(token);
3. Заходим в "Visual Studio", жмем F1, вводим "gist" и выбираем "GIST: select profile";
4. Вводим в появившееся окно наш сгенерированный TOKEN, далее вас попросят ввести имя пользователя, то есть ВАШЕ имя привязанное к аккаунту на github.
5. Проверить все ли работает ТЕПЕРЬ